# Position of CSS3 Keyframe Animation Changes Based on Window Size

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm having some troubles with keyframe animation using CSS3. The position of the image being animated changes based on the window/screen size. I've tried to find a solution to this problem but I'm lost. I tried to specify a boundary so the animation only plays inside that, but it did not work.

See [here](http://www.theprophec.com/tdr), and try resizing the window. I know this has something to do with the `position:absolute`. My ultimate goal was to have the space background move left to right but still be dead in center if that makes sense.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

---

The problem is that the margin-left and margin-right properties are being set to auto, which adjusts the left margin of `tdr-main`, while `space-bg`'s animation modifies the absolute left position. When the window is resized to a smaller size, the left-margin on `tdr-main` shrinks down to 45px, but the left position on the background image still moves betweens an absolute 342px and 450px.

If you embed `space-bg` inside the same container that has the auto margins on it,

```
<div id="tdr-main">
        <div id="space-bg">
        </div>
        [...]
</div>
```

then both will stay centered, and the position on space-bg will be relative to the centered container div. Just use z-index with absolute or relative positioning to keep things stacked correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I tried doing that, but I'm still having the same problem. I moved `tdr-back` inside of `tdr-main` which has the margins left and right set as auto. Please note that `tdr-main` is the main graphic, while `tdr-back` is the space background that is moving. Sorry, I changed some of the terminology.